# Investigation on supplier - Swedish Public Procurement Act

Tags: european-union, sweden, legal-tender, government-contracts

Which documents/certificates can a public contract authority demand a supplier to provide according to Chapter 15 sections 6, 7, 8 of the Swedish Public Procurement Act?

How are those documents named (in Swedish) and from which authority do they come from?

Thanks in advance to anybody who will answer!